# shell script to automatically restart tomcat if stopped

Tags: linux, shell, tomcat, cron

I am using a shell script to start tomcat server if it is not running. I am running this script in cronjob to check it frequently. This is my script

```
#! /bin/sh
SERVICE=/etc/init.d/tomcat7
STOPPED_MESSAGE="Tomcat Servlet Engine is not running."

if [ "`$SERVICE status`" -eq "$STOPPED_MESSAGE" ]; then
     $SERVICE start
fi
```

But whenever I run this script, it gives me an error. If tomcat is not running then the error is :

> [: ILLEGAL NUMBER : * Tomcat Servlet Engine is not running.]

And if tomcat is running the error is :

> [: ILLEGAL NUMBER : * Tomcat Servlet Engine is running with pid 6130.]

I think the error is related to $SERVICE status but I am unable to resolve it. I am a new bee to shell scripting. Please help me out.

I cannot move forward until I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

`-eq` expects 2 integers for comparison (see `man test`).  You should use `=` there for strings.

Or, could you be more tolerant about output from the script?

```
if $SERVICE status | grep -q "not running"; then
    $SERVICE start
fi
```

Of course it would be much better to use a process monitoring tool like [monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/) or [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/).